# RSS feed invalid: <status> service unavailable</status

Tags: rss

When I try to validate my rss feed, I get this result (with w3c feed validator)

This feed does not validate.

line 1, column 39: Undefined root element: status [help]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><status>Service unavailable.</status>
```

But my feed does NOT contain that status tag.  I have no idea where that is coming from?

This is the link to the feed: https://www.vrmodelphotography.com/feed/  I did a search on "status" and I did not receive any hits ...

I do have a background in IT, but it's been a few years and maybe this is a stupid question ... but I can't find any resources on it in google ... and I'm desperate at this point ...

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

So for future reference, if anybody has the same problem ... I had the plugin "under construction" activated.  This plugin allows me to work on my website and showing me the design, menu, ... while the rest of the world just sees an under construction page.

It appears as if this plugin was a bit too ambitious and also shut down the RSS feed.